# set-aduser Homedrive pipe $_.name

Tags: powershell, pipe

Please can you help me with this one liner, and I really need to stick to one line on this occasions:

Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like "test*"} -Properties * | ForEach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -HomeDirectory \servername\directory\$_.name }

Homedrive would come up as \company.internal\Data\HomeDrives\CN=Test1,OU=Staff,OU=Vanilla,DC=company,DC=internal.name

For the test purposes just placing -HomeDirectory $_.name it would work fine.

Please please if you have suggestion for one liner.

thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 0):

Sorted

Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like "test*"} -Properties * | ForEach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -HomeDirectory \company.internal\data\HomeDrives\$($_.name) }